# Django Admin Dashboard ImageField Problem

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

In my django admin dashboard i made a model for an ImageField, problem is that i will use that for a carousel but for that i need to upload more than one image, django limits to only uploading 1 image at a time, and i tried looking around for about 3 hours and i couldnt find any solutions for it, everytime i find something either it doesnt work anymore or its not what im looking. So overall i just want a solution for the Choose Files button when i click it i can choose more than one file/img

i tried looking for solutions for more than 3 hours and couldnt find anything that would work

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow !

Are you trying with Bulilt-in Django admin panel ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ImageField can store only one image.
What can you do:

Make separate model for image:

```
#models.py
class MyImage(model.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('my image', default=None)
    
    #here you need to specify what model this images will be related to(which model you want to add several images with ImageField) lets say it is model "MyModel"
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel,
                          on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                          related_name='images')

    def preview(self):
        # this is needed to see model as actually image in admin
        full_url = str(self.image.url)
        return format_html('<img src="{}", width=200, height=200>', full_url)
```

then you need to add it as inline in admin:

```
#admin.py
from .models import Image, MyModel
from django.contrib import admin

class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    extra = 1
    fields = ('image', 'preview')
    readonly_fields = ('preview', )


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [ImageInline]



admin.site.register(Image)
```